# pip commands failing with retry NewConnectionErrors

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a few packages using pip 20.0.2 on python 3.8.10 using WSL2 and Ubuntu 20.04 (having previously successfully installed numpy and a few others) and now I'm suddenly getting the below error on every pip request; the below is from running `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` but I'm getting similar on `pip install matplotlib` and others.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4997f583a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4997f58ca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4997f58580>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4997f85f70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4997f858b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/pip/
```

I've tried disabling my automatic proxy network settings, using several different wifi sources including hotspot and VPN and nothing is working. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you installing into a venv or are you updating he ubuntu system python?  I'd blow away your ubuntu image, resinstall for WSL and do your updates in a virtual environment.  That will allow you to use a more modern python version.